# Hosting RESTFul api on sub-subdomain in heroku?

Tags: heroku

I was developing this app on Ruby On Rails where I created RESTFul json api hosted on subdomain "api". When testing locally with prax on a linux machine, I was able to test my endpoints by routing to various endpoints like

- "api.app_name.dev/resources"
- "api.app_name.dev/resources/1".

Now, I have been instructed to host the Rails application on free heroku account for the time being so that other developers can test the api.

However,I can't get it to work. The main application is already a subdomain to heroku app itself.The url for the main application is "app_name.herokuapp.com". I can't connect to "api.app_name.herokuapp.com" as it is the sub-subdomain of the application.

Is there any way I can test my api from heroku? Or possibly any workaround ??

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to set correct subdomain constraint in routes, something like

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json },
      constraints: { subdomain: 'api.app_name' }, path: '/'  do 
... thing 
end
```

Also, if it helps, check [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/350-rest-api-versioning?view=asciicast) if of any help